# How automatically update/refresh connectionString at runtime

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-4, app-config

I've app using EF and connect it to database and use my local server on computer to test it. Now, I want give  it to another person. I've executed sql script and have there same database as on my own. Before I can use it, I have to change connection string, but I don't want make that person to read config file and make changes, or even make him know that he have to change anything.
Is there any way that I can "reload" connection string in code(more specific just Data source) using database name.

For example, when creating connection string usind ADO.NET I can make new and while doing that choose from existing databases, and VS create connection string. Basicly, I want same behaviour, a code that will, base on database name reload(or create again) connection string every time somebody run application.

Is refreshSection() in configurationManager after modifying Initial Catalog enough?

Answer (score 0):

It is much more common to use separate config files when supporting multiple environments. Basically you would give him his own config file with the necessary differences. 
The downside is of course that you have to synch new changes in two files now.

You can automate the process of deploying the appropriate config file for each particular environment

Comment: Can you give me link or explain who do that? It's first time I'm doing application for somebody else so I don't have experience to decide what is the best way. 
How can I automate that proces and get appropiate config file ot make app be runnable on any computer that has running server and database?

For example, I tried at home on laptop and I had to change data source part in connection string before running it.